# New Blender User with a Mouse Problem

Tags: 3d-mouse

Perhaps I should have been more specific with my mouse question.  I am a new Blender user with a Logitech MK300 mouse.  I am watching the "First Steps with Blender" tutorial.  I have used the Logitech SetPoint to set the scroll wheel to a middle mouse button (MMB). The tutorial says I can hold the MMB and rotate the view to any angle.  This isn't working; all the scroll wheel does is zoom. I've looked through some of the links and still can't find a solution.  Any suggestions or do I just get flamed again?

Comment: In the browser, if you scroll the wheel it scrolls the page, if you click the wheel it shows a movement icon, and scrolls as you move away from icon, if you click the mmb (hold down) and drag it both moves the icon and scrolls.  This mmb clicking and dragging is how you rotate the view in blender.  [Consult the manual on mouse settings](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/input.html#mouse)  If your mouse doesn't do this [logitech support](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/product/wireless-desktop-mk300)

Comment: Instead of asking a new question, edit your original question ( https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/92010/1853) to clarify what you want.

Comment: Logitech SetPoint and similar "management" software will only create problems and cause possible conflicts between what is essentially a regular mouse and whatever software you are trying to using.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question again, but rather edit your [first one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/92010/2217).

Comment: Any 3 button mouse by default, with no software modifications will function in blender as you describe (Hold MMB to rotate the view).

Answer (score 3):

I still think your question is not specific to Blender. I bet that if you have some other software that makes use of the middle mouse button you would find the same result in that software too.

First of all, the scroll wheel is supposed to zoom. It's when you actually push it downward (not scrolling) that it functions as a button. In Blender if you push it down like this and then move your mouse around you will see your viewing angle change in the 3D Viewport.

Second, make sure your mouse buttons are configured correctly. Although it is for a different model, [here is a page](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/article/20533?product=a0qi00000069v2WAAQ) explaining how to configure what the buttons do on a Logitech mouse in Windows. Here is [another page](http://support.logitech.com/en_us/article/26975) explaining how to do it in macOS.